# Python: How to translate multiple excel IF conditions to python coding?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, if-statement

I have a very huge excel dataset with multiple columns containing multiple IF conditions. One such columns has the following formula:

```
=IF(A2532="Merlin",IF(LEFT(D2532,8)="RMZ.JPWK",RIGHT(D2532,LEN(D2532)-8),IF(LEFT(D2532,6)="RMZ.JP",RIGHT(D2532,LEN(D2532)-6),IF(LEFT(D2532,4)="RMZ.",RIGHT(D2532,LEN(D2532)-4),D2532))),IF(AND(A2532<>"Merlin",LEFT(D2532,4)="RMZ."),"",D2532))
```

Sample dataframe is as follows:

```
#Country    Code
=================
Merlin  010566
Merlin  RMZ.JP828802
Merlin  RMZ.JP828804
Merlin  RMZ.JP828806
Merlin  RMZ.JPNS9002
```

The above condition is simple to be implemented in excel. Gist of the condition is:

```
    If Country is Merlin, then:
        If first 8 characters of D2532 is RMZ.JPWK, then write first 8 characters of D2532
        else if first 6 characters of D2532 is RMZ.JP, then write first 6 characters of D2532
        else if first 4 characters of D2532 is RMZ., then write first 4 characters of D2532

    If country is not Merlin then:
        if first 4 characters of D2532 is RMZ., then write 'NAN'
```

Expected output Dataframe:

```
#Country    Code    Result
================================
Merlin  RMZ.JPWK821517  821517
Merlin  RMZ.JPWK14202   14202
Merlin  RMZ.JPWK14324   14324
Merlin  RMZ.JPWK4003175001  4003175001
Merlin  RMZ.JP828802    828802
Merlin  RMZ.JP828804    828804
Merlin  RMZ.JP828806    828806
Merlin  RMZ.02029182001 02029182001
Merlin  RMZ.02031790001 02031790001
Merlin  RMZ.02519593001 02519593001
Sorex   RMZ.02519593001 NAN
```

I can write the solution for this by creating multiple columns satisfying each condition and then using if else loop, but that is taking a long time to run since the dataset is very huge.

Also it increases my work of cleaning up the dataframe because of the multiple columns created  for each and every condition which is not actually evaluated every time.

Please note the above dataframe is just a small part and actual database contains 100s of columns and 100 thousand rows.

Solution i am looking for is :

1. Eliminate the need to create new columns for each condition and still be able to evaluate it in a single expression.

-2. Eliminate the use of If loop

Comment: Have you read any pandas guides, the documentation, etc.?

Comment: Yes, as i said, i can solve this by creating multiple columns and if else loops but that making my script very slow.

Comment: I know, I read your post, that doesn’t really answer my question.

Comment: Have you considered splitting your columns? The `Code` column has a clear pattern to it, you would only benefit from separating its parts.

Comment: I believe we are also missing key parts of your data. Please read how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing formulas in Excel anymore so do not bring the same mindset to the job. Your actual problem is two-fold:

1. To extract the numeric code at the end of the `Code` column
2. Assign those numeric codes to the `Result` column according to the country

Regex is a good tool for the first task. The second can be achieved with dataframe slicing:

```
# Extract the numeric code, for all countries
code = df['Code'].str.replace(r'RMZ.*?(\d+)', '\\1')

# Check if the country is Merlin for each row
is_merlin = df['Country'] == 'Merlin'

# Create the Result column
df.loc[is_merlin, 'Result'] = code
df.loc[~is_merlin & df['Code'].str.startswith('RMZ.'), 'Result'] = 'NAN'
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Any specific documentation you can suggest where i can read more on how to work on such scenarios

Answer (score -2):

Your sample output and pseudo conditional makes zero sense. You are writing something completely not the outcome in your sample.

The simple answer is use a csv, iterate across it using python and save the results you are looking for. Forget about translating it to excel.

You can reimport a csv into an excel anyways.

Just write a CSV parser "," and you are good to go.

-Everytime you find new line character you know it's a new row.
-Everytime you find a row you are looking for store the entire row or write it to a new file.

## Use regular expression.

Eliminate the use of if loops? You can't. The only way you will know if an element match is using a conditional and the only way you will get through a set of data is iteration through it.